# Mac Mini Without Monitor/KB/Mouse

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I’m thinking about getting a Mac Mini for app development purposes. My main machine is a Surface Book 2 which is where I do all my development.

My question is: can I use a Mac Mini without a monitor, keyboard and mouse? Just remote into it through the network? If that’s possible,  what about the initial setup? I suspect I’d need a KB, mouse and a monitor at least for initial setup. Is that the case?

As I said, my main machine is a Surface Book 2 and I want to keep my desk clutter free. It would be wonderful if I can have only the Mac Mini on my desk in addition to my Surface Book 2 and simply remote into the Mac Mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need a keyboard, mouse and monitor to setup the Mac.
After that you can enable Screen Sharing from System Preferences -> Sharing.
Then you can use a VNC client to connect to the Mac.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to make sure I’m clear, after initial setup, I won’t need a monitor, keyboard or a mouse, correct?

Comment: Correct. You just turn on the Mac and the VNC server on the Mac starts and you can connect to it.